# Writing equation at right of image

Tags: graphics, tikz-feynman, feynman, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I want to write an equivalent expression correspond to an image. A representative image should look like

[image]

So far I tried

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \scalebox{0.4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right=1.3cm of b] (c);
        \vertex[right= 2.0cm of c] (d);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of c] (e);
        \vertex[below left=1.3cm of e] (f);
    \diagram*{
    (a)-- [vanilla] (b),
    (b)-- [vanilla] (c),
    (c)-- [vanilla] (d),
    (c)-- [vanilla] (e),
    (e)-- [vanilla] (f),
    (b)-- [vanilla] (e),
    };
        
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{wrapfigure}
$=e^{3\epsilon\gamma}\mu^{3-3d/2}\int \frac{d^dk_1}{i\pi^{d/2}}$
```

But it is not giving nice look like the representative image, rather gives

[image]

How to change this?

Comment: Please add code so that the example is compilable.

Answer (score 5):

The `wrapfigure` environment is not the right tool.

Here's without scaling and with vertical centering.

I defined a dummy `vanilla` style. Please post compilable examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzfeynmanset{vanilla/.style=}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base)]
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex[below right=3.25mm of a] (b);
    \vertex[below right=3.25mm of b] (c);
    \vertex[right= 5mm of c] (d);
    \vertex[below left=3.25mm of c] (e);
    \vertex[below left=3.25mm of e] (f);
    \diagram*{
      (a)-- [vanilla] (b),
      (b)-- [vanilla] (c),
      (c)-- [vanilla] (d),
      (c)-- [vanilla] (e),
      (e)-- [vanilla] (f),
      (b)-- [vanilla] (e),
    };
  \end{feynman}
  \coordinate [yshift=-2.5pt] (base) at (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
=e^{3\epsilon\gamma}\mu^{3-3d/2}\int \frac{d^dk_1}{i\pi^{d/2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AH, I thought that image was that of the first picture. +1.